# Race Condition in xv6

Tags: unix, linux-kernel, operating-system, qemu, xv6

I am a newbie in the field of OS and trying to learn it by hacking into xv6.My doubt is can we decide before making a call to fork whether to run parent or child using system calls.i,e i can have a function pass an argument to kernel space and decide whether to run parent or child to run first.The argument can be:
1-parent
0-child.

Comment: And what would you need that for? How do you guarantee the child is not scheduled out before it does whatever you want it to do?

Comment: I neee  it in order to control the scheduling policy.by default it is parent first.I would like to control whether to run child first or parent based on the argument through a system call.The child would not be scheduled before because i would make the system call to decide the policy before calling fork.

Comment: This does not answer my question. Let me state the obstacle once more. Say you schedule the child to run first. It runs, starts executing some code and is scheduled out. Now the parent gets the cpu. What was the purpose of having the child run first and how did you guarantee the purpose was fulfilled? For instance, if the child was supposed to do 2 actions, chances are it could only do 1. Or to state differently, so far it looks like you are trying to do something wrong.

Comment: If you need to do something before the child runs and don't care about chid's pid, do it prior to forking. If you need to wait for the child to do something, just wait for the child to notify you it did the thing you are waiting for. This can be implemented by e.g. having a shared page. The child can be instructed to wait in a similar manner if really needed. Either way, games with scheduling sound fundamentally wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that `fork()` just creates a copy of the process and makes it runnable, but the module responsible for allowing it to run is the scheduler. Therefore, the parameter you mentioned should also provide this information to the scheduler in some way.

If you manage to do that, I think you can enqueue the two process in the order you prefer in the `runnable queue` and let the scheduler pick the first runnable process.

However, you cannot control for how long the first process will run. In fact, at the next scheduling event another process might be allowed to run and the previous one would be suspended.